# IndexOutOfBoundsException and quicksort algorithm

Tags: java, quicksort, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having trouble figuring out why my code has an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I was wondering if someone could be my extra pair of eyes to help me catch the error. I am trying this out by hand but I think I am missing something as I go through the code.

code:

```
package Algorithms;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class quickSort {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> mergeArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> min, int pivot, ArrayList<Integer> max) {
        ArrayList<Integer> mergedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //mergedList.addAll(min);
        for (int i : min) {
            mergedList.add(i);
        }
        mergedList.add(pivot);
        //mergedList.addAll(max);
        for (int j : max) {
            mergedList.add(j);
        }
        return mergedList;
    }


    public static ArrayList<Integer> quicksort(ArrayList<Integer> array, int min, int max) {
        if (array.size() <= 1) {
            return array;
        }
        int pivot = (min + max)/2;
        ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i : array) {
            if (i <= array.get(pivot)) {
                less.add(i);
            }
            else {
                greater.add(i);
            }
        }
        return mergeArrayList(quicksort(less,min,pivot - 1), array.get(pivot), quicksort(greater, pivot + 1, max));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for (int i : arr) {
            arr1.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(quicksort(arr1,0,arr1.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at Algorithms.quickSort.quicksort(quickSort.java:30)
    at Algorithms.quickSort.quicksort(quickSort.java:37)
    at Algorithms.quickSort.main(quickSort.java:46)
```

Comment: @peter.petrov sure thing boss

Comment: What happens when `min == max`? What is the value of `pivot + 1` in your next recursive call to `quicksort` in that case? You've skipped an important condition in the quicksort algorithm (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort, in particular `if left < right`).

Answer (score 1):

Add this line for debugging purposes at the start of your `quicksort` method.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> quicksort(ArrayList<Integer> array, int min, int max) 
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array.toArray()) + " -> " + min + " " + max);
    ...
}
```

You will see exactly what is happening and when/where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

quicksort(greater,pivot + 1, max) in the return will result in:

```
int pivot = (max + pivot + 1) /2; //pseudocode
```

pivot will be greater than the length of the array,(which is half the original one) resulting in an out of bounds exception when you ask for array.get(pivot)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the `min` & `max`

I understand that you use them as indexes in the array that you send,
But - you send the `less` & `greater` which are smaller than the original array.

so, for your example , after the first call to `quicksort`, pivot = 2
this part `quicksort(greater, pivot + 1, max)` will send the `greater` with value of 3,4
so this create you exception